# Vegas.js Not Displaying Background Properly on Wordpress Theme

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins, wordpress-theming, slideshow

I'm using a pre-designed Bootstrap 3.0 theme from Bootstrap Wrapper and incorporating it into a Wordpress theme. The Bootstrap site usings vegas.js as a header background/slideshow feature on the site. It works perfectly when I have it all on a root folder, but when I incorporate it into a Wordpress theme the div that displays the background-image shows url('site'/none). Any clue on why this is happening? I've included the vegas.js at the footer of the Wordpress site.

Heres the HTML output and jQuery code:

HTML Output:

```
<div class="vegas-loading></div>
<div class="vegas-overlay" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image: url(http://katecolfeltwp/none);"></div>
```

Vegas jQuery:
/* VEGAS Home Slider */

```
    $.vegas('slideshow', {
          backgrounds:[

            { src:'../img/slider/01.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'../img/slider/02.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'../img/slider/03.jpg', fade:1000 },
            { src:'../img/slider/04.jpg', fade:1000 }
          ]
        })('overlay', {
          src:'none'
        });
        $( "#vegas-next" ).click(function() {
          $.vegas('next');
        });
        $( "#vegas-prev" ).click(function() {
          $.vegas('previous');
    });
```

If you have any suggestions I would really appreciate it. I've also used

```
 <?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>
```

at the front of the image url and had the same issues.

Comment: How are you including jQuery?

Comment: Im using the wp_register/wp_enqueue_script -        wp_register_script('vegas', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.vegas.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), null, true);                     <?php wp_enqueue_script('vegas'); ?>

Comment: One thing I would try to exclude is if this is related to path problems of not finding the images. Try adding a full path to one image to see if that is shown.